# Object joining with entity framework table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a c# class

```
public class VendorLocation
{
    public string VendorCode { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

and a List

```
var lstVendorLocation = new List<VendorLocation>();
```

The following LINQ query get compiled and throw an exception at run time:

```
var query = from s in DB.Sales
           where lstVendorLocation.Any(vendorLoc => s.VendorCode.Equals(lstVendorLoc.VendorCode) && s.Location.Equals(lstVendorLoc.Location)) 
           select s;`
```

The exception message is:

> Unable to process the type 'Anonymous type, because it has no known mapping to the value layer

Comment: Why you put tag C# in title and didn't in tag box?

Comment: What is the origin of `lstVendorLocation`? You should try to use it as the original `IQueryable` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

How could you get a items from `lstVendorLocation` when the current status is empty?

Did you mean like this?

```
var query = from s in DB.Sales
           where ...
           select new VendorLocation
           {
              ....
           };`
```